# How to identify nude images? (or something similar?)

Tags: photos

I've done some research and so far haven't found anything very helpful. My question is what technology can I use to identify at least most nude images, etc. when being upload from users to my site and not allow them to be posted? From what I understand, there isn't anything "perfect" of course but I would like to get a good start with something half decent verses nothing at all what-so-ever. Any suggestions, links, or helpful bits of information are *greatly appreciated*!

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365313/how-to-block-uploads-of-nude-images

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

Comment: I wonder if this could not be done using similar algorithms that Google uses to pick up faces in photographs, except that your algorithm would have to pick up vaginas, boobs and the like.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a histogram of the images and check for the amount of skin-tone-ish pixels.

Comment: Wouldn't that only catch Caucasian porn? `:)`

Comment: @hexa your idea is best i think . can u please guide how to start

Answer (score 2):

I would go the route of building your own.

Here is a good project that has helped me in my first attempts at image recognition

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BackPropagationNeuralNet.aspx

There has been a lot of success with writing tools that look for nude images. Generally speaking, they look for certain amounts of skin-tone and/or shapes. Those will flag potential images for human review.

good luck!

Comment: You're going to need lots and lots of source material to train the net.

Comment: It looks like somebody finish the project https://github.com/notAI-tech/NudeNet/