# Is it possible to check an image for anything containing Pornographic?

Tags: c#, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to programatically detect porn images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images)

is it possible to check an image being uploaded to a site for anything containing pornography? I've heard of tools that process the image to check for flesh tones, but have no experience or knowledge about them.

I am using ASP.NET/MVC/C#

Comment: I do not see how that is possible, would be interesting though.

Comment: There is actually a post I have seen on SO about this. _runs off to find it_

Comment: Yep, this is a dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365313/how-to-block-uploads-of-nude-images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713247/what-is-the-best-way-to-programatically-detect-porn-images

Comment: I wonder what color range you need to include tentacles, robots, furries, .... ok - goes off to lie down quietly in a dark room.

Comment: It's impossible to do reliably, but you can use flesh tone analysis as part of a risk scoring system to prioritise human review.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Nude.js](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/nudejs/). It is a JavaScript implementation of a nudity scanner based on approaches from research papers.