# iOS Filtering Images for Adult Content

Tags: ios, image, filtering

Are there any available APIs, libraries, or open-source solutions to filter images for pornographic content based on the images themselves?

Comment: You mean based on the images themselves? That would be a challenge. Or do you mean some kind of database of URLs?

Comment: Based on the images themselves. That is indeed a real challenge! I know methods have been studied and implemented, but I haven't found anything usable for mobile development.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was an effective solution out there. Though I would be happy to be proven wrong. Apple are so obsessed by this, they should provide it. NSPornDetector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some commercially available solutions, mentioned in the questions below.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404588/image-nudity-detection
2. [PHP - Blocking of uploaded adult images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010763/php-blocking-of-uploaded-adult-images)

None of those are available on iOS, and none of them are 100% accurate.
The best they can do is flag images for inspection by a real person.

A possibility is that you could pipe images through mechanical turk, using their api. You would be paying for every image inspection, but not a lot, so perhaps it's doable depending on your business model.

You could couple mechanical turk with a skin detection algorithm using OpenCV, to only inspect images that contain skin... which would cut down the cost of image inspection.

Skin detection alone wouldn't work, as there are wayyyy too many false-positives (bald people, skimpy clothing).

Comment: That's probably as far as this will get, thanks for your input!