# How to find out adult images uploaded by users in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, image-processing

We have an application where users can upload images and those images will instantly show up on our website.

Last week, when one person, uploaded a bunch of XXX-Rated pictures and things showed up immediately on the website. Luckily, we noticed and removed them in matter of a few minutes. Still, that time was enough to shock some of our other users.

Here is my question:

- How to effectively analyse and block such images from being uploaded?
- If there is no effective library,60-70% of filtration will be acceptable. So that admin panel can show up notifications and we can take actions.

I am thinking of something that once image has been uploaded, run that filter on image and if there is some issue pass that image to admins to approve it, basically hold the display on website before it get approved.

Comment: You would be talking about having image recognition.  Not a simple task: http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html

Answer (score 2):

Even though I couldn't find an answer, the following are some interesting  threads which discuss the same:

[How to block uploads of nude images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365313/how-to-block-uploads-of-nude-images)

[PHP - Blocking of uploaded adult images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010763/php-blocking-of-uploaded-adult-images)

And most of the comments suggest an manual reviewing solution, not an automated one (their point makes sense: there is no boundary to define an 'adult image').

And the following is a commercial solution:

[Crowdflower](http://crowdflower.com/)

Comment: Then How companies like pinterest is managing this? I am talking about total xxx images.